# jquery, tablesorter filter and menu: menu goes away when overlap

Tags: jquery, css, menu, tablesorter

I have a page where I am using a tablesorter component and a jquery menu. tablesorter is using the filtered row search feature which appears on a mouse hover. Problem is, as soon as the menu is down and mouse comes over the tablesorter hidden row, row goes out and menu goes away.
How can I prevent the tablesorter filter row from popping out when menu is down?

You can see my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/V9a7b/14/

```
                       <nav id="MyMenu">
                            <ul>
                                <li>&nbsp;</li>
                                <li>&nbsp;</li>
                                <li>&nbsp;</li>
                                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                                    <ul id="MenuAction">
                                        <li><a href="#">Action 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Action 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Action 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Action 4</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Action 5</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Action 6</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Action 7</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Account</a>
                                    <ul id="MenuAccount">
                                        <li><a href="#">Change&nbsp;Password</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">View&nbsp;Accounts</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Create</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">View&nbsp;Roles</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Log&nbsp;off</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>&nbsp;</li>
                                <li>&nbsp;</li>
                                <li>&nbsp;</li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>

<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="PackagesTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Field 1</th>
            <th>Field 2</th>
            <th>Field 3</th>
            <th class="filter-select filter-onlyAvail">Status</th>
            <th>Field 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="PackageList">
    <tr class="PackageRows" id="Tr1">
        <td><a style="text-decoration:none" href="#">test1</a></td>
        <td>test #11</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Sent to QA</td>
        <td><span class="time">2014/04/09 18:45:01</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="PackageRows" id="Tr2">
        <td><a style="text-decoration:none" href="#">test2</a></td>
        <td>bla bla...</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Active/In Development</td>
        <td><span class="time">2013/12/17 18:36:35</span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        $("#PackagesTable").tablesorter({
            theme: 'blue',
            widthFixed: false,
            widgets: ["zebra", "filter"],
            widgetOptions: {
                filter_filteredRow: 'filtered',
                filter_hideFilters: true
            }
        });

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the [`filter_hideFilters` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-hidefilters) to `true`. The filter widget adds a class name of `hideme` to the filter row. This class name essentially makes the filter inputs disappear and yet you can still use tab to get to them. See [the css here](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/css/theme.blue.css#L174-L193).

The only time the `hideme` class name is removed is when any filter input has a value, any filter input has focus or the user hovers over the filter row.

What I'm not seeing is the situation described where the dropdown menu is overlapping the filter row and the pointer is brought over the filter row to make it expand. At least not in Chrome and Firefox.

If you see this behavior in a different browser, then why not just set the `filter_hideFilters` option to `false`.

Comment: The menu disappears when the menu is down and the mouse comes over the filter row. I see this in Chrome and Firefox. I want to have the filter row to be hidden and show on mouseover, if possible.

Comment: I think the menu just needs a z-index: `nav ul { z-index: 100; }` http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/V9a7b/15/